# Custom css for hr tag

Tags: html, css

I'm declaring css for hr tag like ..

```
hr { 
    height: 2px !important;
    background-color: #A2B1B9;
    width: 9%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top:auto;
  }
```

But the width of the hr tag dosen't always need to be the same as per the text that it is supported with. Please refer to the screen shot.
[image]

In this case I can either supply differen width along with the hr tag using inline css like . But as inline css dosen't fit to the ethical standards of web development is there any other approach that I could follow to make it dynamic?

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear sorry, do you mean that the `hr` does need to be the same width as the text it's under? Or doesn't need to be? And I don't think @devopsEMK's link is strictly relevant

Comment: You cannot make hr element width to be dynamic, use border-bottom to the element insted

Comment: yes,the 'hr' should be the same width as the text

Comment: @devopsEMK could you share a demo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HI now try to this way

Create a class and used to this css .
it's the best option for your .

```css
.customHr{
 padding-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom:solid 2px black;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Custom Text here</p>
<p><span class="customHr">Custom Text here</span></p>
<p>Custom here</p>
<p>Custom Text</p>
<p><span class="customHr">Custom</span></p>
<p>Custom Text here</p>
<p>Custom Text here</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rohit Azad's answer is best, but if for "ethical" reasons you would rather use an hr, you can wrap it together with the text to get the same length.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Text here</span>
  <hr>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span>T-t-t-t-t-text here</span>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Underline instead by putting the text in  tag and then custom css for that.